# PyQt5 QtMultimedia shows black screen on playing H.264 video

Tags: 18.04, video, gstreamer, qt5, pyqt5

We are using a tool based on PyQt5 for some video processing. Since a few days some users complain, that the tool shows only a black screen instead of a video. Sound is still working. 
We were able to reproduce this problem with a small script:

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, path, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        video_widget = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(video_widget)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(self, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.player.setVideoOutput(video_widget)
        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)))
        self.player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    file = "<file>.MP4"
    w = MainWindow(file)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The strange thing is, all users use the same desktop based on Ubuntu 18.04, but only a few users are affected by this problem. I cannot see any differences on their installation which might be related to this problem. 
I have found a bunch of related issues, most of them are outdated. It seems to be some kind of a gstreamer problem. But I do not know to dig deeper into this topic.

Comment: Playing videos with "gst123 --verbose" reports different pipelines on the systems:
1. it works with `gstreamer pipeline contains: GstPlayBin ( GstPlaySink ( GstStreamSynchronizer GstBin ( GstVideoConvert GstDeinterlace ) GstBin ( GstXvImageSink GstQueue GstPlaySinkVideoConvert ( GstIdentity GstVideoConvert GstVideoScale ) ) ) GstURIDecodeBin ( GstFileSrc GstDecodeBin ( GstTypeFindElement GstQTDemux GstMultiQueue GstMpeg4VParse avdec_mpeg4 ) ) GstInputSelector )
`

Comment: not: `gstreamer pipeline contains: GstPlayBin ( GstPlaySink ( GstStreamSynchronizer GstTee GstBin ( GstVideoConvert GstDeinterlace ) GstBin ( GstVaapiSink GstQueue GstPlaySinkVideoConvert ( GstIdentity GstVideoConvert GstVideoScale ) ) GstBin ( GstPulseSink GstQueue GstPlaySinkAudioConvert ( GstIdentity GstAudioConvert GstAudioResample ) ) ) GstURIDecodeBin ( GstFileSrc GstDecodeBin ( GstTypeFindElement GstQTDemux GstMultiQueue GstH264Parse GstCapsFilter GstVaapiDecodeBin ( GstVaapiDecode GstQueue GstCapsFilter GstVaapiPostproc ) GstAacParse avdec_aac ) ) GstInputSelector GstInputSelector )`

Answer (score 0):

Different pipelines for some users on different systems but not for other users point to a problem with VAAPI. Everything works after disabling VAAPI according to the instructions at [Temporarily skipping vaapi decoders in decodebin](https://fhackts.wordpress.com/2018/04/16/temporarily-skipping-vaapi-decoders-in-decodebin/).

---

Sometimes it can be useful to disable vaapi from the gstreamer auto-plugging logic, e.g. when there is a pending issue, or when in need to force the decoder choice in decodebin for testing purposes.

The standard possibilities are:

- removing gstreamer-vaapi alltogether
- overriding the plugin ranking system to demote the vaapi plugins below other alternatives — This requires using the gstreamer API, not available with gst-launch or totem.

I found out an easier way: defining the LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME to a fake value, which will enforce vaapi to fail initializing, hence skipping its plugins.

For instance:

```
LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=fakedriver gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///tmp/file.mp4
```

Without it:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file://`pwd`/bbb-1920-1080-30.mp4
Got context from element 'vaapisink0': gst.vaapi.Display=context, gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)"\(GstVaapiDisplayGLX\)\ vaapidisplayglx0";
```

With the env var, we can see that avdec_h264 has been selected instead:

```
LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=fakedriver gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file://`pwd`/bbb-1920-1080-30.mp4 -v
...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/avdec_h264:avdec_h264-0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)4.1, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640029ffe1001b67640029acca501e0089f970110000030001000003003c8f18319601000568e93b2c8b, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true
```